# How to sort a list using reactjs without sortable.js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to implement a mechanism, where I can drag and drop a list item to a different position using reactjs. I have thought hard about this, but i cannot come up with an algorithm.

My code is

```
return (
  <ul>
    {items.map((item, index) => (
      <li>{item}</item>
    ))}
  </ul>
)
```

Comment: You can use `Array.prototype.sort()` for example where you can pass a compare function. Read further here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort

Comment: i see. but how do i use this function, when i know that a dragged item needs to be at a different index? could u post an answer with an example please?

Comment: @user12912544 use `life-cycle` or `useEffect`, or simply write the sort behind `render()` and before its' `return`

Comment: Why do you even have to sort anything at all? Use something like `react-draggable`, `react-beautiful-dnd`, or something similar to visually move items on the screen.

Comment: @goto1 how do i save the state of the sorting using react-draggable? it seems like a good idea to use it

Comment: Do you want to implement drag-drop or sorting? both are completely different things.

Comment: Look at the documentation for those libraries. They expose events that you can hook to, such as `onStart`, `onDrag`, `onStop` (this is for `react-draggable`) which will tell you which item was moved, then you can do whatever you want with that information.

Comment: @goto1 i see, than you!

Comment: @goto1 hello again, ive looked at react-draggable, but it doesnt say how to handle vertical lists, and from the example i can see that u can drag an item into any position on the canvas, but i want the children to snap. Can u post an answer with an example on how to use it with a vertical list please?

Comment: `react-draggable` will work with any list, not just "vertical" or "horizontal" - that's up to you how you present your list visually to the user. Have a look at `react-beautiful-dnd` and see if this will suite you better - what you're trying to accomplish is achievable with both libraries.

Comment: @goto1 thank you sir. u have been most helpful today.